# Mocha 'should' - identical strings that 'should.equal()' but cause Uncaught AsseritionError

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, should.js

I'm getting this error from Mocha:

```
Uncaught AssertionError: expected 'long-title-abcdefghijklmnopqrs' to equal 'long-title-abcdefghijklmnopqrs'
```

This doesn't make any sense because those strings appear to be equal. Here's the test code:

```
it('shortens and joins title to 30 characters and with -', function(done){
    article.createMdArticle('long title abcdefghijklmnopqrstubwxyz', 'the bod', function(err, doc){
      if(err) throw err;
      doc.url_title.should.eql('long-title-abcdefghijklmnopqrs');
      done();
    })
})
```

and this mongoose pre('save') hook which creates url_title from title

```
articleSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    //makes 'test title' into 'test-title'
    this.url_title = this.title.split(' ').join('-').substring(0,30);
    console.log(this.url_title);
    next();
});
```

All of my other tests that compare any other object data work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... in my articleSchema mongoose schema...

```
var articleSchema = new Schema({
    title : { type: String, index: { unique: true, required: true }},
    body: { type: String, required: true },
    url_title: { sype: String},
});
```

on the `url_title` line, it says `sype: String` instead of `type: String`. When I corrected this, the error was no more.